# @EnableGlobalMethodSecurity vs @EnableWebSecurity

Tags: spring, rest, spring-security, spring-boot

I am developing a REST API using Spring 4. I would like to secure some of the endpoints using Spring Security, but based on what I've read this can be done with either `@EnableGlobalMethodSecurity` or `@EnableWebSecurity`. Unfortunately, the documentation that I have found for these don't clearly explain what they do (or how they compare). If I want to secure a Spring REST API with authentication and authorization based on data and relationships declared in a standard relational database, what is the recommended method for achieving this in Spring 4?

Answer (score 77, accepted):

`EnableWebSecurity` will provide configuration via [HttpSecurity](http://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/current/reference/htmlsingle/#jc-httpsecurity). It's the configuration you could find with `<http></http>` tag in xml configuration, it allows you to configure your access based on urls patterns, the authentication endpoints, handlers etc...

`EnableGlobalMethodSecurity` provides AOP security on methods. Some of the annotations that it provides are `PreAuthorize`, `PostAuthorize`. It also has support for [JSR-250](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JSR_250). [There are more parameters in the configuration for you](http://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/current/reference/htmlsingle/#method-security-expressions)

For your needs, it's better to mix the two. With REST you can achieve everything you need only by using `@EnableWebSecurity` since `HttpSecurity#antMatchers(HttpMethod,String...)` accepts control over Http methods

Comment: Can you expand slightly on the last paragraph? What about my needs makes it better to mix the two?

Comment: You can use URL patterns to make decisions of if a resource needs authorization or not, the `GlobalMethodSecurity` will provide in which action a certain user can perform within the method, eg. a User name John is authorized to access `/foo/maria`, but then the `@PreAuthorize` intercepts it, because it has a SpEL telling the user's name must equal the name at path variable. If you need only authorize or not a certain URL `EnableWebSecurity` will provide all you need