# Spring security WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter configuration issue

Tags: java, spring, spring-security

In the following class that extends `WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter` i've overwritten the `configure(HttpSecurity)` method.

```
@Configuration
@EnableGlobalMethodSecurity(securedEnabled = true)
public class SecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter{

@Autowired
public void configureAuth(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
    auth
            .inMemoryAuthentication()
            .withUser("fabio")
            .password("123")
            .roles("ADMIN")
        .and()
            .withUser("joe")
            .password("123")
            .roles("GUEST");

}

@Override
protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
    http
            .authorizeRequests()
                .antMatchers("/post/list").permitAll()
                .antMatchers("/admin/**").hasRole("ADMIN")
                .anyRequest().authenticated()
            .and()
            .formLogin()
            .and()
            .logout();
}
}
```

With this i should be able to get to `localhost:8080/post/list` page without having to commit to a user login since it has the `.permitAll()` , but when i try to getting into it it always prompts the login page before, only after i enter the previous credentials i'm able to view it. How can i fix this ?

controller class

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/post")
public class HomeController {

    @Secured("ROLE_GUEST")
    @RequestMapping("/list")
    public String list(){
    return "list...";
    }

    @Secured("ROLE_USER")
    @RequestMapping("/drafts")
    public String drafts(){
        return "drafts...";
    }

    @Secured({"ROLE_ADMIN","ROLE_USER"})
    @RequestMapping("/add")
    public String add(){
        return "adding...";
    }

}
```

Comment: Try with `.antMatchers("/post/list**").permitAll()`

Comment: It doesn't work

Answer (score 0):

According to the `@RequestMapping` definition there is a conflict because it is secured by annotation `@Secured("ROLE_GUEST")` but also you need to access it with `.permitAll()` configuration.

Option 1: Just remove the `@Secured("ROLE_GUEST")` in order to let `.permitAll()` do the work.

Option 2: use `@Secured("ROLE_ANONYMOUS")` on the `@RequestMapping("/list")` instead of `@Secured("ROLE_GUEST")`.  You can see the definition of `ROLE_ANONYMOUS` in the [Spring Documentation](https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/3.0.x/reference/anonymous.html)

---

It will depends on the path value after `/post/list`.  Please see the following examples of how to define `antMatchers` depending on the path value.

`localhost:8080/post/list`  =  `.antMatchers( "/post/list").permitAll()`

`localhost:8080/post/list/stuff`  =  `.antMatchers( "/post/list/**").permitAll()`

`localhost:8080/post/list`, `localhost:8080/post/list1234`

=  `.antMatchers( "/post/list**").permitAll()`

For more information visit the [AnthPathMatcher](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/util/AntPathMatcher.html) documentation and [HttpSecurity](https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/current/apidocs/org/springframework/security/config/annotation/web/builders/HttpSecurity.html)

Comment: that's this `localhost:8080/post/list` , isn't it supposed to work with my code ?

Comment: yes it is, this is how it works, just make sure about something, how  is declared the path on the `@RequestMapping` handler? could you provide it? and also visit this post https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29721098/enableglobalmethodsecurity-vs-enablewebsecurity#29721230